# How to use attached image as src on <img> inside {{html}} in XWiki

Tags: xwiki

I have an embedded html block in an XWiki page using `{{html}}`

Inside this `{{html}}`, I have an `<img>` element. I am able to get it working when the `src` attribute of this `img` is pointing to a public url like "http://example.com/image.png".

But, I couldn't figure out a way to use one of the images attached on this page as the `src`.

Any help is highly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

The best is not use HTML for that and instead use XWiki Syntax 2.0+ to create the attachment link. If, for some reason, you have to use the HTML macro, then pass `wiki=true` to it (and use the wiki markup for defining an attachment link). See the reference documentation at https://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/HTML%20Macro.

The last option is to use the Velocity macro (https://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/Velocity%20Macro) around the HTML macro, to compute the path to the attachment, using the `$doc.getAttachmentURL()` API.

Comment: Unfortunately velocity couldnt be used. I do have wiki=true, but still couldn't get it working. It would be really helpful if you can add an example usage into your answer.

Comment: The format to embed images in XWiki Syntax is ``[[image:attachedFile.png]]``. See e.g. https://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/XWiki/XWikiSyntax?syntax=2.1&section=Images and the Wiki code on the start page of the "Sandbox" which should be preinstalled in your XWiki instance.